# Using findViewById in an external class

Tags: java, class, android-studio, findviewbyid

My app has many elements in the layout (well over 100) and declaring all of them in the MainActivity so as to access them is making my MainActivity class difficult to read and debug.
So I created a new class to handle working with the display elements:

```
public class DisplayElementHandler extends Activity{
private EditText txtUserID;
    public void Initialise(){ //initialise all display elements
        txtUserID = (EditText) findViewById;
    }
}
```

However the `findViewById` does not work as I expected it to.

I am an Android Studio/Java newbie and this one has me stumped - can anyone help please?

Comment: Well, first Java is not a "script".  Second, you might want to [read the manual.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#findViewById(int)), and maybe [learn some Java syntax.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html)

Comment: In your  `DisplayElementHandler` class, save of an instance of the activity (the context), during the activity's onCreate() or somewhere, and use this to call `findViewById(...)`. Why is the `DisplayElementHandler` class inheriting from `Activity`?

Comment: Fair Enough - point taken - I'm actually a PHP developer so I dont have all the lingo down pat for Java.

Comment: Abhishek - is this the "protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);}" code similar to what is in MainActivity? - as to "extends Activity", that is from one of my "attempts to sort the problem out - (NEWBIE ;>}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to delegate work done by your `Activity` to your Handler class. Extending `Activity` makes the Handler it's own activity (another screen), which isn't really what you want here. It should interact with your existing Activity.

This can be achieved a number of ways, but I would pass a reference to your activity to your Handler in the constructor, like so:

```
 public class DisplayElementHandler {
      private Activity activity;
      public DisplayElementHandler(Activity activity) {
           this.activity = activity;
      }

      public void Initialise(){ //initialise all display elements
           txtUserID = (EditText) activity.findViewById(...);
      }
 }
```

And then in your `Activity`:

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle b) {
      super.onCreate(b);
      new DisplayElementHandler(this).Initialise();
 }
```

You may also want to pass the R.id reference to the view into the Handler as part of the constructer as well.

Comment: emerssso - does this mean that I should have created a new "Activity" and not a new "Java Class"?

Comment: Nah, just a java class that you can use in your activity. I'll expand the answer to make that clearer.

Comment: emerssso - Thank you for your help (and patience) - I got a small part working and it looks good in testing so far. Using this technique will make my main program section far less cluttered and far more readable, especially when I need to do the changes that **will** be required once the users get hold of it.

Comment: Update: Getting all sorts of errors happening: null returns, incompatible types (expecting this, getting that). Looks like I will be publishing the "messy" version (from a developer and coding (OOP) point of view). I have been informed that 2 "screens" need to be replaced with other content but that is for a later date - no "mission creep" allowed thank you. Hopefully I can get the code and functionality cleaned up and working by that release. Java seems to be "low level" and unforgiving and the error reporting is far too technical for Newbies. Android Studio has a way to go to be "friendly"

Answer (score 0):

Well, 100 elements in one class is a lot. Maybe think about it and find a way to reduce that :D

You try to call your elements from an external class, so you have to tell in which class your elements are. The way you did just searches in the current class.

Comment: Fingu - It is a lot - it started off with 36 layouts - I shaved that down to 1 layout that holds 5 text Question/Answer pairs and 5 radio groups which I hide or show depending on what the requirements are and of course change texts all over the place - the 36 layouts was even a bigger mess of spaghetti